# Virtual Function vs CRTP

Tags: c++, performance, crtp

I am trying to run a simple measurement test on both virtual function and CRTP using VS2010 , its a simple console programme where , I am writing to a text file 10,000 times , what I am observing in the release version  at times whenever I am running through IDE by CTRL + F5(start without debugging) , I see a major performance boost with virtual function calls however at the same time when , I am running the programme through windows explorer as an administrator, I see a major performance boost with CRTP , I am really curious why this is happening . my code as follows:-

```
class CFileProfile
{

public:
CFileProfile()
{
    if(!m_file.Open(_T("C:\\File_logger_opt.txt") , CFile::modeCreate|CFile::modeWrite))
    {
        printf("\n Error In Opening File \n");
    }
}

~CFileProfile()
{
    m_file.Close();
}

static CFileProfile* GetDefault()
{
    if(m_pMe == NULL)
    {
      m_pMe = new CFileProfile;
    }

    return m_pMe;

}

static void ReleaseDefault()
{
    if(m_pMe)
    {
        delete m_pMe;m_pMe = NULL;
    }
}

CStdioFile* GetFile()
{
    return &m_file;
}

static  CFileProfile* m_pMe;
CStdioFile m_file;

};

template<typename CRTP_ARGS>
class CBase_CRTP
{
public:
void Execute()
{
    CRTP_ARGS::ExecuteA();
}
    };


class CDerived_CRTP : public CBase_CRTP<CDerived_CRTP>
{
public:
   static void ExecuteA()
{
    CString sLine;
    sLine.Format(_T("\n Executing CDerived_CRTP \n"));
    CFileProfile::GetDefault()->GetFile()->WriteString(sLine);

}
};

class CBase_WCRTP
{
public:
virtual void Execute()
{

}
};


class CDerived_WCRTP :public CBase_WCRTP
{
public:
virtual void Execute()
{
    CString sLine;
    sLine.Format(_T("\n Executing CDerived_WCRTP \n"));
    CFileProfile::GetDefault()->GetFile()->WriteString(sLine);
}
};


Inside Main:-
    CFileProfile::GetDefault();

SYSTEMTIME sys_time;
::GetSystemTime(&sys_time);
CString sLine;
sLine.Format(_T("\n The Virtual Start :-[%d:%d:%d:%d] \n") , sys_time.wHour , sys_time.wMinute , sys_time.wSecond,sys_time.wMilliseconds);
CFileProfile::GetDefault()->GetFile()->WriteString(sLine);

CDerived_WCRTP wcrtp;
for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
{
    wcrtp.Execute();
}

::GetSystemTime(&sys_time);
sLine.Format(_T("\n The Virtual End :-[%d:%d:%d:%d] \n") , sys_time.wHour , sys_time.wMinute , sys_time.wSecond,sys_time.wMilliseconds);
CFileProfile::GetDefault()->GetFile()->WriteString(sLine);



::GetSystemTime(&sys_time);
sLine.Format(_T("\n The  CRTP Start :-[%d:%d:%d:%d] \n") , sys_time.wHour , sys_time.wMinute , sys_time.wSecond,sys_time.wMilliseconds);
CFileProfile::GetDefault()->GetFile()->WriteString(sLine);

CDerived_CRTP crtp;
for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
{
    crtp.Execute();
}

::GetSystemTime(&sys_time);
sLine.Format(_T("\n The  CRTP End :-[%d:%d:%d:%d] \n") , sys_time.wHour , sys_time.wMinute , sys_time.wSecond,sys_time.wMilliseconds);
CFileProfile::GetDefault()->GetFile()->WriteString(sLine);



CFileProfile::ReleaseDefault();
```

Comment: If you don't tag a language nobody will look at it. In project > debugging > environment try `_NO_DEBUG_HEAP=1` and see if it has any effect.

Comment: Surely the bottleneck is writing to the file and not the function call overhead?

Comment: Thanks for your comment Neil , I will keep in mind to include language tag next time.., your advised worked , I am getting 30% boost with CRTP while/when I m running it with ctrl + F5/start without debugging , how ever if I run it from windows explorer as an admin I am getting exactly same performance seems like both CRTP and virtual function are same if I am executing it from windows explorer previously CRTP was 50% faster , I m still a bit curious